# How to write authorize function correctly in typescript for nextauthjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to use [Credentials Provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials) with NextJs ("next": "^12.0.7") and NextAuth ("next-auth": "^4.1.2"). I am writing this in typescript, and facing issues in getting the function correctly.

Here's my `/pages/api/[...nextauth].ts`

```js
import NextAuth, {  } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { verifyOTP } from "@/lib/otp";

// {
//   user: {
//     id: 1,
//     username: null,
//     phone: '+919876543210',
//     phoneVerified: true,
//     email: null,
//     emailVerified: false,
//     active: true,
//     token: 'SOME TOKEN',
//     createDate: null
//   },
//   result: 'approved'
// }

export default NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signup',
    newUser: '/signup',
    error: '/signup'
  },
  debug: false,
  secret: "SOME_SECRET",
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials: {
        username: {label: "username", type: "text", placeholder: "markandre"},
        phone: { label: "Phone ", type: "text", placeholder: "+919876543210" },
        otp: {  label: "OTP", type: "text" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials, _req) => {
        try {
          const res = await verifyOTP(credentials!.phone,
            credentials!.otp, credentials?.username);
          if (res.result === "approved") {
            return Promise.resolve( {
              id: res.user.id,
              email: res.user.email,
              name: res.user.phone,
              token: res.user.token
            });
          }
        } catch (e: any) {
          //const errorMessage = e.response.data.message;
          //throw new Error(errorMessage);
          return Promise.reject(null);
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60, // 3 hours
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({token, user}) => {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.token
      }

      return token;
    },
    session:async ({session, token}) => {
      if (token) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      }
      return session;
    }
  },
  events: {
    signIn: async (message) => {
      console.log('signIn', message);
    },
    signOut: async (message) => {
      console.log('signOut', message);
    },
    createUser: async(message) => {
      console.log('createUser', message);
    },
    updateUser: async(message) => {
      console.log('updateUser', message);
    },
    linkAccount: async(message) => {
      console.log('linkAccount',message);
    },
    session: async(message) => {
      // console.log('session', message);
    }
  }
})
```

When I am building this app, I keep getting the error

```
./src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts:36:7
Type error: Type '(credentials: Record<"username" | "phone" | "otp", string> | undefined, _req: Pick<IncomingRequest, "headers" | "body" | "query" | "method">) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<"username" | "phone" | "otp", string> | undefined, req: Pick<IncomingRequest, "headers" | "body" | "query" | "method">) => Awaitable<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<Omit<User, "id"> | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<Omit<User, "id"> | { id?: string | undefined; } | null>'.
    Type 'Promise<Omit<User, "id"> | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Omit<User, "id">'.
      Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Promise<Omit<User, "id"> | null | undefined>'.

  34 |         otp: {  label: "OTP", type: "text" }
  35 |       },
> 36 |       authorize: async (credentials, _req) => {
     |       ^
  37 |         try {
  38 |           const res = await verifyOTP(credentials!.phone,
  39 |             credentials!.otp, credentials?.username);
info  - Checking validity of types .%
```

My `.tsconfig` looks like below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,

    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "out",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,

    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/public/*": ["./public/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["./out/**/*", "./node_modules/**/*"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `authorize` function needs to return either an object representing a user or `false`/`null` if the credentials are invalid.

Your current logic isn't explicitly returning `false`/`null` for the case when the `res.result === "approved"` check is false, hence the type error. You can fix this by explicitly returning `null` after the `if` block.

```js
authorize: async (credentials, _req) => {
    try {
        const res = await verifyOTP(credentials!.phone, credentials!.otp, credentials?.username);
        if (res.result === "approved") {
            return {
                id: res.user.id,
                email: res.user.email,
                name: res.user.phone,
                token: res.user.token
            };
        }
        return null; // Add this line to satisfy the `authorize` typings
    } catch (e: any) {
        //const errorMessage = e.response.data.message;
        //throw new Error(errorMessage);
        return null;
    }
}
```

As a side note, you also don't need to wrap the user object and `null` with `Promise.resolve()`/`Promise.reject()`, so I've also omitted those.

Comment: The OP states a typescript issue relating to the `credentials` input, and your answer goes into details about return type, which is not the culprit here.

Comment: @Morriz The `Promise<Omit<User, "id"> | null | undefined>` type the error refers to is the return type of the `authorize` function. The last line of the error states: _"Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Promise<Omit<User, "id"> | null | undefined>'"_, this is related to the return type.

Comment: @Morriz That being said, I'm not claiming it's the actual solution to OP's issue, as they never got back to me. It could very well be a bug like you said it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug not yet solved: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2701.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is still in the NextAuth latest version of 4.20.1

To fix the issue you just need to correct one type issue in the return User interface that they only consider your data for ID is string and not number type, which is fine as usually using this provider will be visiting database and most of them are returning string not number

```js
CredentialsProvider({
      id: "password",
      name: "Email and Password",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "john@gmail.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
        const user = { id: '1', name: 'J Smith', email: 'test@example.com' };
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }),
```

Make sure you return the User object with ID using string like 1 to "1" will fix the type issue, do not need to change tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me by setting the **strict** mode from *true* to *false* in **tsconfig.json**.

**See the image below.**

[image]

Comment: Never do this. So your code is no different from js

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, make sure that the user object that is returned by the authorize function has "id" property with a numeric string value like so:

```
authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
        await connectDB();
        try {
          if (!credentials?.username) {
            return null;
          }
          if (!credentials?.password) {
            return null;
          }
          const user = {
            id: "1",
            username: "bellonell@gmail.com",
            name: "Bello shehu",
          };
          // fetch user from db
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
```